# Single insert vs. muliple inserts

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I'm iterating a (binary) file and insert some values in a table.
After receiving the values I insert them row-by-row in the database.

Part of my code (example values):

```
string sColumn1 = Getcolumn1Value();
string sColumn2 = Getcolumn2Value();

string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) " +
                      "VALUES (@column_1, @column_2)";

SqlCommand cmdInsPacket = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, connection);

cmdInsPacket.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column_1", sColumn1);
cmdInsPacket.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column_2", sColumn2);

cmdInsPacket.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdInsPacket.Parameters.Clear();
```

Because there're millions of records I was wondering if it's beter to insert a group of, for example, 500 instead of one by one.

Any good suggestions to fix this (and is my suggestion (group insert) useful)

(MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and C#)

Comment: You should look up for Bulk Insert

Comment: I thinks you are using excell sheet if there are million of records so,Upload the data through excell to SQL SERVER.

Comment: Not an Excel sheet ! (It's a binary file - proprietary format) Direct import in SQL server not possible.

Comment: Hello Robertico what is binary file ?

Comment: @Nayeem Mansoori: Not containing plain text, but need to process bytes. But that's not my problem. Single insert works fine but looking for solutions to speed up inserts

Comment: As long as you keep your connection open, it probably won't make any difference whether you insert one by one or a few at a time.  Any potential gain you might achieve with inserting groups might be lost as you check to see that you still have 500 records left.

Comment: @Robertico: this might help you understand that it won't matter much: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/10/08/240123.aspx (of course, unless you are using bulkcopy)

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: I keep my connection open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to insert multiple records. You can put records in datatable and save them to db in single call.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))     
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =  "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";
    try
    {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newProducts);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, this should be a comment, since it is not a (direct, self-contained) answer.

Comment: It's more than 2 columns and what about memory usage (datatable) ? Also want to avoid datatables (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

**If you have the data in DataTable format use this simple function.**

```
function static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable bulkData)
{
    using(SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ProductHost;Initial     Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
         dbConnection.Open();
         using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
         {
            s.DestinationTableName = "Your table name";
            foreach (var column in bulkData.Columns)
            s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
            s.WriteToServer(bulkData);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the data in DataTable format but from a foreach loop. Do i need to create a datatable equal to the SQL table and fill it with 500/1000 rows and than run bulkcopy, clear table..fill again etc ?

Comment: then what type of data you have?

Comment: Do you meand this: 
[column1] [char] (45) NULL,
[column2] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[column3] [char](15) NULL,
[column4] [char](15) NULL,
[column5] [int] NULL,
[column6] [int] NULL,
[column7] [char](3) NULL,
[column8] [int] NULL,
[column9] [char](17) NULL,
[column10] [char](17) NULL

Approx. 1,200,000 records per file and up to 40,000,000 per batch

Comment: This is your table definition right? however you said you have a binary file. so if you could read it and store it into DataTable using loop. then you have a fresh Datatable. so use that to store into SQL Table

Comment: What about the memory usage of the DataTable. The SQL DB is approx. 1.6 GB for 12,003,024 records.

Comment: its pretty huge. in that case why are you coding here. you can directly import the data to another database using SQL query? you do it by programming it will take a while

Comment: Binary data files - proprietary format. Direct import in SQL server not possible

Comment: if you are going to import it only once. just do it by your code. no problem. and you said its proprietary format. so it's the better way. datatable is much faster compare to any other arrays or anything

Comment: since it's proprietary format. you know how to read it efficiently. so read it however you want and store it into datatable.

Comment: Thanks for thinking and suggestions !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43872/discussion-between-robertico-and-kirk)